# Handling nested data in reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, angular-reactive-forms

I have to do a `POST` so we often make something like this:

```
const userData = this.userForm.value;
```

Suppose in the template you have:

```
<input type="text" id="userName" formControlName="userName">
<input type="email" id="userEmail" formControlName="userEmail">
<select id="userTypeId" formControlName="userTypeId">
  <option *ngFor="let userType of userTypes" [value]="userType.id">{{userType.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Then in your `userData` you'll have:

```
{
  userName: 'foo',
  userEmail: 'foo@bar.com',
  userTypeId: '1'
}
```

This is fine, but now your API is waiting for:

```
{
  userName: string,
  userEmail: string,
  userType: UserType
}
```

where `UserType`

```
{
  id: string,
  name: string,
}
```

so you eventually do:

```
const userForAPI = {
  userName: userData.userName,
  userEmail: userData.userEmail,
  userType: { id: userData.userTypeId }
}
```

and then you go to

`this.userService.createUser(userForAPI)`

Now, I want to know if there is a possible alternative solution for not doing:

`userType: { id: userData.userTypeId }`

I mean, if you can model the template based on the api's model so that you can send `this.userForm.value` to the api.

Comment: I'd say that the best alternative would be to fix the API: why does it ask for a user object with an ID and a name if all it actually needs is a user ID? That said, there is nothing wrong in having a form structure that doesn't match the API command structure, and to adapt the structure before posting the request. The form structure should be the one that is needed by the form in the web page, not the one needed by the API.

Comment: It was my first impression but it is requested but an API made in graphql, so I am really what is called a mutation nos just a simple call. For now, the point was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for the select/option control can be custom object, and not just strings, if you use `ngValue` instead of `value`. This means that you can change your model to use `userType` instead of `userTypeId`.

```
<select id="userType" formControlName="userType">
  <option *ngFor="let userType of userTypes" [ngValue]="userType">{{userType.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The model will now contain, for example, the following.

```
{
  userName: 'foo',
  userEmail: 'foo@bar.com',
  userType: {id: '1', name: 'foo1'},
}
```

---

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-46023613).

Comment: @FacundoGFlores Tried it out and added a demo; it works for me. It might be something else causing the problems in your case.

Comment: I missed the `[ngValue]` it is working, sorry. Just one thing, do you know why `patchValue` is not working? I mean I am sending the object correctly to the form but there is not "selecting" the user type.

Comment: Updated the demo, you can see that it works (`baz` is displayed instead of the initialized `foo`).